# How can I copy and combine several .txt lists in alphabetical order?

Tags: command-line, files, text-processing

I have several `.txt` files containing contact lists from different phones, how can I combine these while avoiding duplicates in alphabetical order using the terminal?

**example:**

contacts1.txt:

```
John
Bob
Steve
```

contacts2.txt:

```
Amy
John
```

output.txt:

```
Amy
Bob
John
Steve
```

Comment: Can you give and example how such a txt file could look like?

Comment: @chaos done (a phone number would follow the name on the same line) :)

Comment: And will the phonenumbers always be the same?

Comment: @terdon no but they follow the names on the same line, I would think the letters of the names would come before the numbers in any alphanumerical sorting.

Comment: If so, chaos's answer won't work, you'll still have duplicates since the numbers are different. Please [edit] your question, show us an example that represents the data you have and your desires output. How should the multiple phone numbers be dealt with? Would you like something like `name phone1 phone2`? Should they  only be considered as duplicates if the names are identical?

Comment: @terdon I don't mind having duplicates if the numbers are different, that way I can check what numbers are still in use. Maybe there is a way to do this with the terminal though, as in have the most recent list have a priority over possible duplicates? I don't know. I don't have many contacts who have changed numbers so I don't mind checking manually because say that person has two active numbers one in each list? no command line will know how to deal with that.

Comment: OK, in that case, chaos's approach is what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just:

```
sort -u *.txt >output.txt
```

Or with `uniq`:

```
sort *.txt | uniq >output.txt
```

---

`sort` will sort all input lines given by all `*.txt` files. `uniq` removes dublicate lines (the same as sorts `-u` flag).

The file `output.txt` contains:

```
Amy
Bob
John
Steve
```

Comment: Or indeed `sort -u *.txt`

Comment: Would that create an output file or do I have do copy and paste?

Comment: `sort -u …` is enough

Comment: @dragonsarefake add `>output.txt` to the end. I updated the answer.

Comment: @chaos Thanks! I have to wait minute before I can mark as answer.

Comment: @chaos I can't edit but you marked `outout.txt` instead of `output.txt`

Comment: @dragonsarefake was a typo, corrected